# ocaml type from a code example, please

Tags: ocaml

This might be a basic ocaml type question. Please explain how I can get the type of below code as `('a * 'a) list -> 'a list` from ocaml toplevel.

```
let rec func lst = match lst with
|[] -> []
|h::t -> match h with
|(a,b) -> if (a = b) then a::(func t) else b::(func t);;
```

Comment: Note that a `match` with a single pattern can be done with a `let` binding. Instead of `h::t` and then matching on `h` you might: `(a, b)::t -> if a = b then a :: func t else b :: func t`. Of course, you might also: `(a, b)::t -> (if a = b then a else b) :: func t`.

Answer (score 4):

Let's go though one by one to check the type of the code. At the first line, `func` in the code represents the name of a function and lst is a tuple list since we use match with `lst` and got `[]->[]`  and `(a,b)->`  and we have a=b (a and b have same type, I forgot to mention this before Thank you for pointing out), so `('a*'a) list`. Now, let's check the output of the `func` function. At the fourth line, it calls `func` itself recursively and its return value is a list since by the definition of `::`,  `x` is a value and `y` is a list in `x::y`. Because a list in ocaml is homogeneous, the type of the list would be same as the value `a`. The type of the value `a` is `'a` because the `a` value came from `(a,b)`. Thus, it has a type `('a * 'a) list -> 'a list`.

Comment: Thank you so much. so it has a' list because the a value is type a' right?

Comment: Well, `a` and `b` must have the same type, so the `b` value is also type `'a`. The reasons `a` and `b` must have the same type are (1) the expression `a = b` requires this; (b) the `then` and `else` branches of an `if` must have the same type.

Comment: Just to clarify, I believe that @JeffreyScofield's comment shows how GentleCoder's answer is misleading in a small way: The match of `h` with `(a,b)` doesn't by itself make the type of the input `('a * 'a) list`; it's only because of `a = b` and/or because of the last two uses of `::` that the compiler knows that the input has type `('a * 'a) list` and not `('a * 'b) list`.  That last type, `('a * 'b) list`, is one that does not require that `'a` and `'b` be the same type.